# Visualizing Error Between Two 3D Images using Marching Cubes

Tags: python, 3d, visualization, pyvista

I am attempting to visualize the error between 2 3D nrrd images using marching cubes and Pyvista. I computed the Euclidean distance between the two images and am attempting to take the isosurface of an image and use the Euclidean distance information to visualize the error.

```py
import numpy as np 
import pyvista as pv 
import nrrd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
  
img1 = nrrd.read("image1")
img2 = nrrd.read("image2")
  
distance = np.linalg.norm(img1-img2, axis=2)
distance = distance.flatten()
 
grid = pv.UniformGrid()
grid.dimensions = img2.shape
grid.spacing = (1,1,1)
grid.point_arrays["Distance"] = distance
isovalue = 1000
contour = grid.contour([isovalue], scalars="Distance",method = 'marching_cubes')
 
p = pv.Plotter()
p.add_mesh(contour, cmap='coolwarm', opacity=0.5,scalars="Distance")
p.add_mesh(grid.outline(), color='k')
p.show()
```

I am attempting to get a result similar to this:

https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/01-filter/flying_edges.html#sphx-glr-examples-01-filter-flying-edges-py

However I am receiving an error:

```
data length of (62748) != required length (15624252) for > grid.point_arrays["Distance"] = distance.
```

I do not quite understand what the issue is. As I am taking the isosurface of image2 and using the Euclidean distance information as the scalars in the pyvista post to visualize the error.

Comment: Please remember to follow the posting guidelines for [asking a good question](/help): use correct markdown (e.g. don't quote code, put it in code fences, and use inline code markup for inline code). Also, if you're getting an error, remember to [show the real error](/help/how-to-ask), i.e. just copy and paste it, including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: the last spatial dimension of your 3d images has length 249.

Here's a reproducing example (sans `nrrd`; also note that I've switched to the "new" `point_data` attribute introduced in PyVista 0.32.0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

shape = (100, 101, 102)
img1 = np.random.rand(*shape)
img2 = np.random.rand(*shape)

distance = np.linalg.norm(img1 - img2, axis=2)
distance = distance.flatten()

grid = pv.UniformGrid()
grid.dimensions = img2.shape
grid.spacing = (1, 1, 1)
grid.point_data["Distance"] = distance
```

This gives us

```
ValueError: data length of (10100) != required length (1030200)
```

So what happened? We ended up with `100 * 101` values instead of `100 * 101 * 102` values. This is unsurprising, since we started from a 3d array the same size as our uniform grid, but then we reduced the last dimension using the norm.

So your 3d images must be grayscale, meaning that in each voxel you have a single value (rather than an RGB(A) sequence). So when you take `img1 - img2` you already have a single value (i.e. a scalar) at each voxel; there's no point in reducing the data using any kind of norm.

There are two possibilities:

1. Your data is correct, in which case just drop the norm and use the (absolute?) difference of the images.
2. Your data is actually meant to be RGBA (or otherwise 4d), in which case you have to fix the arrays and do the reduction along the appropriate (channel) axis.

Comment: Yes that's correct on the size of the image. The images are binary images, not RBG.